# Access $app object from controller

Tags: php, slim

How to get access to $app inside a controller as the Slim 3.3 injects only the ContainerInterface?

Code to illustrate the question:

```
$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/home', 'HomeController:get');

$app->run();

class HomeController {
    private $ci;

    public function _construct($ci) {
        $this->ci = $ci;
    }

    public function get($request, $response) {
        $this->ci->get(...);
        // How to access $app and dependencies like $app->jwt?
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your Slim version?  `\Slim\Slim::getInstance();` an option?

Comment: Just use `global` I think is the DI pattern ;) Naw, read this one?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365258/access-app-in-class-in-slim-framework-3

Comment: @ficuscr I added the information to the post. I'm using the version 3.3 so the getInstance deprecated.

Comment: @ficuscr The $app object injection using the container generates an exception 'Slim Application Error'. Otherwise it's a nice one!

Comment: @MaxBündchen you don't need to ever get the $app instance. There is nothing on the $app instance anymore everything is stored in the container which is why we inject it.

Comment: @geggleto I see some extensions that inject into $app objects like jwt for json web token authentication. I inject the relevant information in the container from the original $app->jwt so I don't need the app as you said (that make much more sense and are much more test friendly), but I got curious about this problem.

Comment: @MaxBündchen this is a common pattern in Slim v2... It's super easy to confuse v2 with v3. The dead giveaway is the $app object is Slim\Slim in v2 and Slim\App in v3. Service location via injecting into the $app is the classic pattern for v2. Dependency Injection is the pattern for v3.

Answer (score 1):

This was a tough one.

Slim 3 heavily uses dependency injection, so you might want to use it too.

First inside your dependencies.php you need to grab the $app and throw it in a container to inject it to the Controller later.

```
$container['slim'] = function ($c) {
   global $app;
   return $app;
};
```

Then you got to inject it:

```
// Generic Controller
$container['App\Controllers\_Controller'] = function ($c) {
    return new _Controller($c->get('slim'));
};
```

Now on your controller.php:

```
private $slim;

/**
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface       $logger
     * @param \App\DataAccess                $dataaccess
     * @param \App\$app                      $slim
     */
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, _DataAccess $dataaccess, $slim)
    {       
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->dataaccess = $dataaccess;
        $this->slim = $slim;
    }
```

Now you just got call it like this:

```
$this->slim->doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own 'singleton' to mimic `Slim::getInstance();` ;)

```
class Anorexic extends \Slim\App {
    private static $_instance;
    public static function getInstance(){
        if(empty(self::$_instance){
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

Then change your initialization like this:

```
// $app = new \Slim\App;
$app = Anorexic::getInstance();
```

Now you can get your `\Slim\App` instance anywhere in your code by calling `Anorexic::getInstance();` Ofcourse you should never try this at home :P